# How to do the registration form automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am using selenium with java , cucumber , j unit and Gradle.

on my registration form there are many fields which has the validation message.

For example username field gives below error messages 
1) When use the existing username giving "Username already exists
"
2) Empty username giving " required " validation message 
3) Its only allowing to create username which contains a-z and 0-9 if not then giving "can only contain a-z and 0-9" message

Do i need to create the separate tests to check this validation message? Like below

```
 Feature file : 
@usernamevalidation
  Scenario Outline: Username already exist

    When Click on SignUp
    And username is '<username>'
    And phone is '<phonenumber>'
    And Email is '<email>'
    And companyname is '<companyname>'
    Then validation of username and email

    Examples: :

  | username | phonenumber | email | companyname |
  | romalwinn888554  | 65236523 | phurbadolma@yahoo.com | AAA |
  | laroche | 789654456 | phurbadolma@yahoo.com | AAA |
  | macharya1 | 786541212 | phurbadolma@yahoo.com | AAA|

Method : 
 public void userAlreadyExist(){
        utils.waitForElements(useralreadyExist , KnowsTestContext.timeout , KnowsTestContext.driver);
        String actual = useralreadyExist.getText();
        String expected = "Username already exists" ;
        Assert.assertEquals(actual , expected);
    }

    public void emailAlreadyExist(){
        utils.waitForElements(emailalreadyExist , KnowsTestContext.timeout , KnowsTestContext.driver);
        String actual = emailalreadyExist.getText();
        String expected = "Email already exists" ;
        Assert.assertEquals(actual , expected);
    }
```

Is it possible to do all the validation in one method  ?

Comment: Are these can't be covered in unit/ API level tests?

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, the answer to "Do i need to create the separate tests to check this validation message?" is: **Yes**.

In general, it is advisable to create separate tests for each test case.

**Reasons:**

- Combining several tests will make the tests more clumsy.
- Unless it is a step in the test, you should not have an assert till
  the final step validation.
- Debugging the failures will become more complicated, if you keep
  adding multiple validations from different paths to a single test.
  The real complexity comes when you have to debug tens of failures
  from random flaky tests, everyday.